# What do ε₀ and V mean in a Pourbaix diagram?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

From [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pourbaix_Diagram_of_Iron.svg):

[image: Pourbaix Diagram of aqueous Iron]

What does this graph mean?

What is $\varepsilon$?  It looks like $\varepsilon_0$, like the vacuum permittivity, but what does this have to do with the polymorph and/or isomers of ferrite or hematite?

And what is the V or 'five' in square brackets after the $\varepsilon_0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This diagram, called E-pH diagram or Pourbaix diagram, makes it possible to know the domains of existence or of predominance of redox species as a function of pH.

The abscissa is the pH, the ordinate the reduction potential (with respect to the standard hydrogen electrode): thus, it is not a question of the size epsilon but of the potential $E$ which has been a little "stylized" as $\mathcal{E}$, which is expressed in volts (hence the symbol V).

Answer (score 4):

This is a [Pourbaix Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pourbaix_diagram) (I assume this is where you got this figure). While it's not a common notation as far as I'm aware, $\epsilon_0$ is being used to represent the reduction potential in volts (V). As mentioned at the top of the Wikipedia page, this is basically a phase diagram, that tells you the ranges of voltage/pH for which a particular species of (in this case) iron is most thermodynamically favorable. The dividing lines coincide with an even mixture of the surrounding species.

Comment: It's probably meant to be $\mathcal{E}_0$ `$\mathcal{E}_0$`, as in [electromotive force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force).